# Sails js afterCreate

Tags: node.js, model, sails.js

I'm using models in sails and I wrote an afterCreate which just populateAll properties of my new record.

My problem is that when I wrote :

```
Model.create(values, function(err, record) {
   console.log(record)
}
```

the code for after create is :

```
function  afterCreate (object, next) { 
 Model.findOne(id: obj.id)
 .populateAll()
 .exec(function(err, populated) { 
   next(null, populated)
 }
```

The logged record is not populated.

Do you have an idea why I don't get the populated record ?

Thank's !

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem I just created an function in the model called createAndPopulate()

Like that :

createAndPopulate: functuion(values, next) {

```
Model.create(values, function(err, record) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }

        Model
        .findOne({
          id: record.id
        })
        .populateAll()
        .exec(function(err, populated) {
          if (err) {
            return next(err);
          }

          return next(null, populated);
        });
      });
  }
```

And it's work !

Hope it's will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to name obj to object